# Is $\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{1+x^2}\ dx$ divergent or convergent?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Shouldn't the $|x|$ be equal to $-x$ since I'm in $(-\infty,0]$? But the square root of a negative number is not defined in the reals. Can I conclude that the integral is divergent then?

Comment: $x\in(-\infty , 0] $ so $x ≤ 0 $ so $|x|=-x \mathbin{\color{red}≥} 0$.

Comment: Undefined and divergent are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shooting a bullet in your own foot. You are right to write $|x|=-x$, but immediately forget this and see the square root of a negative !

$\sqrt{-x}$ is well defined for $x<0$.

---

The integral will converge as the asymptotic behavior is that of $|x|^{-3/2}$.

Comment: Ahh... I see... so $-(-x)=x$..

Comment: @Parseval: I don't think you still have understood. The expression $-x$ is not necessarily a negative number.

Comment: But if $x\in(-\infty,0]$, then the expression $-x$ must always be positive?

Comment: @Parseval: why do you say "But" as if you disagreed ?

Comment: Because it is a disagreement based on the fact that I still don't understand why, what you stated in previous comments, is true. I don't question your comment, just trying to understand why it's true.

Comment: When $x$ is negative, $-x$ is positive and conversely.

Comment: But I still feel like I'm using this fact twice. First I use it to convert $|x|$ to $-x$ and then suddenly I use it again to say that $-x$ will always be positive.

Comment: @Parseval: where's the contradiction ? $|x|>0$.

Answer (score 3):

By substitution of $y = -x$ we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{1+x^2} dx = \int_0 ^\infty \frac{\sqrt{y}}{1+y^2} dy = \int_0 ^1 \frac{\sqrt{y}}{1+y^2}\ dy + \int_1 ^\infty \frac{\sqrt{y}}{1+y^2}\ dy$$

While the first summand is finite obviously the second is finite by $$\int_1 ^\infty \frac{\sqrt{y}}{1+y^2}\ dy \le \int_1 ^\infty \frac{\sqrt{y}}{2y^2}\ dy = 1$$

Hence your initial integral converges.

Comment: You don't really address the OP's concern, do you ?

Comment: Thought the first comment already made that clear… still the question in the subject to be answered. And btw: The substitution also should remove the confusion of the OP